# StackPanel in Button.Content inside DataTemplate shows as text

Tags: wpf, button, wpf-controls, datatemplate, wpf-4.0

So I have an `<ItemsControl>` with `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>` defined as `<DataTemplate><Button>...</Button></DataTemplate>`.

This button has a `StackPanel` set as its content. But it shows as "System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel" string and not as actual visual content of the StackPanel.

Why and how to change that?

Comment: I tried what you said, and I do not run into the issue you describe. I see a `Button` with a `StackPanel` in it. Of course, I had to make assumptions about the rest of the code that you did not share, so it probably is not the same as yours. I think some code snippets would be helpful. You are not providing enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: what is in that stack panel ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample depicting your problem. Otherwise with the details that you have shared, the problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I missed the fact that in a custom template used the content was rendered inside a `<TextBlock/>`.